# How to solve "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript based planner application for planning cabinets. In mobile view I am actually getting this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The function which causes this error looks like this:

```
XMLClass.prototype.get = function(varName, thisObject) {
    if (this[varName] instanceof Function) {
        return (this[varName]).apply(thisObject);
    } else if (this.hasOwnProperty(varName)) {
        return this[varName];
    } else if (this.parent) {
        return this.parent.get(varName);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

This is a helper function, which is used during the creation of the article menu. Is the error caused by this function itself or maybe by the used XML-file, which delivers the data for the menu?

Can anybody please help me to solve this problem? That would be really awesome!
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is where the method is called:

```
MobileCabinetMode.prototype.getAlternativeArticle = function(article) {
    if (!(article instanceof Article)) return false;
    depthAlternative = article.getAlternative("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH);
    if (depthAlternative) {
        return depthAlternative;
    }
    var widths = article.getAllAlternative('width');
    for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
        var alternative = planner.artNoArtList[widths[i].artnr];
        if (!alternative.fitsAttribute("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH)) {
            alternative = this.getAlternativeArticle(alternative.getAllAlternative("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH));
        } else if (alternative !== article) {
            alternative = this.getAlternativeArticle(alternative);
        }
        if (alternative instanceof Article && alternative.fitsAttribute('depth', DEFAULT_DEPTH) && alternative.isActive()) {
            return alternative;
        }

    }
    return false;
};
```

The critical point is in line 13:

```
alternative = this.getAlternativeArticle(alternative);
```

Is this enough information for you?

Comment: How is it called? what are the values of the arguments that cause this error?

Comment: Looks like recursion without a base case. You need to answer @alfasin question above, to get an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that only on mobile platform you get this error. This method not causes  " Maximum call stack size exceeded” " , bug is somewhere else...

Comment: @NikolaLukic: Yes. I'm sure that this error only occures on mobile devices.

Comment: Go and find your critical "loop" function. This error comes with infinity loop! You must post best code line to make clear your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I got the answer by the creator of this code. In the end I had to replace the function "getAlternativeArticle" mentioned in my original post, with an already existing (in another file) newer version of itself.
To see the differences, you can view the result here:

```
MobileCabinetMode.prototype.getAlternativeArticle = function(article) {
    // TODO: remove
    if (~this.alternativeSearch.indexOf(article.artnr)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(article instanceof Article)) return false;
    this.alternativeSearch.push(article.artnr);
    depthAlternative = article.getAlternative("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH);
    if (depthAlternative) {
        this.alternativeSearch = [];
        return depthAlternative;
    }

    var widths = article.getAllAlternative('width');
    for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; ++i) {
        var artnr = widths[i].artnr;
        var alternative = planner.artNoArtList[artnr];
        if (!alternative.fitsAttribute("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH)) {
            alternative = this.getAlternativeArticle(alternative.getAllAlternative("depth", DEFAULT_DEPTH));
        } else if (alternative !== article) {
            alternative = this.getAlternativeArticle(alternative);
        }
        if (alternative instanceof Article && alternative.fitsAttribute('depth', DEFAULT_DEPTH) && alternative.isActive()) {
            this.alternativeSearch = [];
            return alternative;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

But nevertheless I want to thank you for your replies and help!